# ASP Core add logging in utility classes

Tags: asp.net-core, ilogger, iloggerfactory

We automatically get the logger injected into the generic controller class. But how do we derive a logger for generic utility classes that have different generic types than the enclosing Controller?

```
public partial class GenericController<T> {
    public GenericController(ILogger<T> logger) 
    {  
          MyUtility<DifferentClass> utlDifferent = new MyUtility<DifferentClass>( /*????*/ );
          MyUtility<AnotherClass>   utlAnother   = new MyUtility<AnotherClass>( /*????*/ );
    }
}
...
public class MyUtility<P> {
    public MyUtility<P>(ILogger<P> logger) { }
}
```

Is there a way to get the LoggerFactory that created the injected logger instance and use it to generate a new logger with all of the same providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `MyUtility<P>`, so inject that instead of `ILogger<T>`.

```cs
public GenericController(MyUtility<DifferentClass> utlDifferent, MyUtility<AnotherClass> utlAnother)
{  
}
```

Avoid directly instantiating objects yourself (with `new ...`). Let the container handle that and just inject what you need directly.

Note: this would be easier if `MyUtility<P>` implemented an interface (like `IMyUtility<P>`) - then you could add it to the container with open generics:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IMyUtility<>), typeof(MyUtility<>));
```

That way you could inject the interfaces instead:

```cs
public GenericController(IMyUtility<DifferentClass> utlDifferent, IMyUtility<AnotherClass> utlAnother)
{  
}
```

Then it would be easier for you to test your controller (by mocking the interfaces).